# How to guess mime type of the binary that is already loaded into memory (using Python)?

Tags: python

I fetch files from an s3 bucket as binary blobs and have to return them via an http response with valid mime type (image/png, text/html, etc.). I found a package called `mimetype` in the standard library that can to do this kind of things but it requires as an argument a path to a file on the file-system and thus an unnecessary write-read operation that I realy want to avoid.

```py
import mimetypes

print(mimetypes.guess_type('test.jpg'))
# ('image/jpeg', None)
```

Can someone suggest a tool for guessing mime types for the files which are already loaded into memory and stored there as Python's `bytes` type.

Comment: `mimetypes.guess_type()` doesn't look at the file contents at all, it just looks up the extension in a table.  All you need here is the original filename of your blob.

Answer (score 2):

`mimetypes.guess_type()` does *not* require an IO operation.  So just use that.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type) say:

> Guess the type of a file based on its filename, path or URL, given by
> url. URL can be a string or a path-like object.

So it's just looking at the string you've provided, not actually opening the file.  We can confirm that by [looking at the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/mimetypes.py#L103), it's basically just comparing the extension to known filetypes.

Comment: thought it works more complicated way than just parsing filename's extension.. thank you for the answear!